# Agora Flutter Sdk Isssue

Tags: flutter, webrtc, agora

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
/C:/Users/Hanzla/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.0.4/lib/controllers/rtm_client_event_handler.dart:76:7: Error: A value of type 'Null Function(LocalInvitation)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dynamic Function(LocalInvitation, String)?'.
- 'LocalInvitation' is from 'package:agora_rtm/src/utils.dart' ('/C:/Users/Hanzla/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtm-1.5.6/lib/src/utils.dart').
      (AgoraRtmLocalInvitation invitation) {
      ^
/C:/Users/Hanzla/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.0.4/lib/controllers/rtm_client_event_handler.dart:81:7: Error: A value of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation, String)?'.
- 'LocalInvitation' is from 'package:agora_rtm/src/utils.dart' ('/C:/Users/Hanzla/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtm-1.5.6/lib/src/utils.dart').
      (AgoraRtmLocalInvitation invitation) {
      ^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 59s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is the error that I am getting while integrating agora sdk in my flutter app.

I am currently using an older version of `agora_rtc_engine` which is 5.3.1 and on this version, I am getting this exception
if I use a newer version it's working fine but I want to run it on flutter web also and flutter web is not supportable on the newer versions.